# Exclude subdomains from analytics tracking

Tags: analytics, tracking, subdomain

I have a website on www.example.com and use Google Analytics. This website has lots of subdomains which I want to track using Google Analytics. It also has some static subdomains like static.example.com which serve all static content.

Google Analytics is issuing cookies on all subdomains but I don't want the static content traffic to be carrying the weight the GA cookies.

Any ideia on how to exclude the static subdomains from being tracked by Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this line of code

```
pageTracker._setDomainName("www.example.com")
```

This will issue cookies for the www.example.com and the cookies won't be leaked to the static subdomain.

Comment: With the new version of Google Analytics (analytics.js) you will use `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);`.